What to do when Safari tab groups don't sync?
My iOS/iPadOS devices suggest that tab groups are synced accross devices. That seems to be also true for my new mac. I can see all tab groups accross iPhone iPad and "newMac".
On my "oldMac" there are tab groups that are not synced, I was surprised. The first thing I checked was if iCloud is activated for Safari on "oldMac" - It was.
I also checked Safari settings, I did not see any setting about syncing tab groups.
Is there anything I have to do in Safari to ensure syncing tab groups from may "oldMac"?
How can I get the tab groups from "oldMac" to "newMac".
Both macs run macOS Sonoma 14.5 and Safari 17.5.

Apparently you can share tab groups. To do so, you hover with your mouse on the name of the tab group and a button with three dots appears. After clicking it the first option is "Sharing Tab Group". Now you can wither share it with yourself via iMessage, but better you don't even need to actually send the iMessage containing the tab group invitation. Just by expressing the intent to share it, safari puts the tab group into icloud and you can see it on your other mac even before completing the sharing process via iMessage.
